# Best Technique for Multiple Eval Fields in Gridview ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, eval

What is the best way to use multiple EVAL fields in a GridView ItemTemplate?

Looking to have some control over formatting for appearance as well as setting up hyperlinks/javascript etc.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Even clearer, IMO, is:

```
<%# String.Format("{0} - {1}", Eval("Name1"), Eval("Name2")) %>
```

Comment: Suppose Name1 is a string say "Obama....." How to get only First 3 Chars using Format string...?

Answer (score 7):

I had previously used this (bad, I know):

```
<%# Eval("Name1", "{0} - ")%> <%#Eval("Name2")%>
```

Result = 'John - Smith'

But just discovered that I can also put TWO (or more) Evals in the same data-bound group:

```
<%#Eval("Name1") & " - " & Eval("Name2")%>
```

Result = 'John - Smith'

Or

```
<%# "First Name - " & Eval("Name1") & ", Last Name - " & Eval("Name2")%>
```

Result = 'First Name - John, Last Name - Smith'

Answer (score 6):

Eval and Bind both suck.
Why get the property through reflection? You can access it directly like this:

```
((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyProperty
```

It's not like the object is unknown to you at runtime. That's my two cents, anyhow.

Comment: Totally like this method, it's clean.

Answer (score 3):

I have a easiest way to do this same thing...

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName").ToString() +", "+ Eval("LastName").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

.

```
<%#Eval("FirstName").ToString() +", "+ Eval("LastName").ToString() %>
```

Here both objects are converted into string the concatenate them.