# Two properties within an Eval

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, binding, textbox

Say I have a textbox that I want to display the FirstName from a database I would go:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

However I want to display both the First and LastName in this textbox.

Is it possible to do this using Eval using the one textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have a separate property called `FullName` that looks like this:

```
public string FullName
{
  get { return FirstName + " " + LastName }
}
```

Then you can reference this property instead of `FirstName`.

Alternatively, you can use `String.Format` to combine both properties inside a single `Eval` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607/best-technique-for-multiple-eval-fields-in-gridview-itemtemplate).

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName") %>
```

or

```
<%# String.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("FirstName"), Eval("LastName")) %>
```