# Eval method, how to bind more than one value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass two values with a navigate URL using Eval method, but it doesn't take more than one value.
Here is my code

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("ReportTitle") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ReportId","GroupId","~/Groups/ReportPage.aspx?ReportId={0}&Group={1}")%>' > </asp:HyperLink>
```

But I have this error(Error3 No overload for method 'Eval' takes 3 arguments) 
so how can i do what i want to?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%# String.Format("~/Groups/ReportPage.aspx?ReportId={0}&Group={1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReportId"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupId"))%>
```

Answer (score 4):

[You might want to review this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607/best-technique-for-multiple-eval-fields-in-gridview-itemtemplate)

One way is:

```
<%# String.Format("{0} - {1}", Eval("Name1"), Eval("Name2")) %>
```